# Update Actionbar smoothly - Xamarin Android

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, xamarin, customization

i am trying to customize my Actionbar and so far i got what i wanted (i need to format it so that it looks nice, but i have the raw design that i wanted).
Now my Actionbar looks like this:

[image: New Actionbar]

But now i am having the problem that my Actionbar looks like this when my app is being started:[image: Old Actionbar]

and after 1-2 few seconds it "jumps" to the design above(when the Activity is fully started).

So my question is if it is possible that at least the right bachground of the Actionbar is being loaded ad start and that the icons appear when the activity is fully loaded (or even if it is possible to load the complete new Actionbar at start)

This is the way i am customizing the Actionbar:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        ActionBar mActionBar = this.ActionBar;
        mActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        mActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.custom_actionbar);
        mActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);



        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
  }
```

And here is the layout for my new Actionbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="#E1E2E3">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="olla" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/back_ico" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ususal1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/butt_toolbar_style"
    style="@style/button_text"
    android:text="abc" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ususal2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/butt_toolbar_style"
    style="@style/button_text"
    android:text="def"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I have also seen that there is such thing as an ActionBar.IOnMenuVisibilityListener which should be called before the Actionbar is being shown, but it somehow never gets executed (or maybe i am dosing something wrong)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you find solution for this?
I had the same problem and had to put a theme to the application element in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```html
styles.xml
<style name="home">
    <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width" >fill_parent</item>
</style>

AndroidManifest.xml 
<application android:label="myappname" android:theme="@style/home">
```

this is what you have to add to make it work.
Leave the rest of the code as is.